# Why is TypeScript not throwing an error here?

Tags: typescript

We're [converting](https://github.com/nfriedly/express-rate-limit/tree/typescript) a Node.js module from JavaScript to TypeScript. In the initial conversion, there is [some code](https://github.com/nfriedly/express-rate-limit/blob/d2272083cedcb710a52d4f988aca1c72686ffcd6/lib/express-rate-limit.ts#L17) that incorrectly defines a type as `string` when it should be `any`. (It's passed to express's res.send() which accepts `any`.)

This is the relevant subset of the code:

```
namespace RateLimit {
  export interface Options {
    message: string; // <-- should be any
  }
}

function RateLimit(incomingOptions: Partial<RateLimit.Options>): RateLimit {
  // ...
}

export = RateLimit;
```

Other users have [reported](https://github.com/nfriedly/express-rate-limit/issues/138#issuecomment-509718641) getting an error when trying to use a non-string here:

```
node_modules/express-rate-limit/dist/express-rate-limit.d.ts:13:9
    13         message: string;
               ~~~~~~~
    The expected type comes from property 'message' which is declared here on type 'Partial<Options>'

    at createTSError (/Users/xxx/IdeaProjects/xxx/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:245:12)
    ...
```

The fix looks straightforward, but before fixing it, I created a mocha [test](https://github.com/nfriedly/express-rate-limit/blob/d2272083cedcb710a52d4f988aca1c72686ffcd6/test/typings-test.ts#L6-L8) for the bug:

```
require("ts-node/register");
const rateLimit = require("../lib/express-rate-limit.ts");

describe("express-rate-limit typescript typings", function() {
  it("should work with non-string messages", () => {
    rateLimit({
      message: { json: "object" }
    });
    rateLimit({
      message: Buffer.from("I'm a buffer!")
    });
  });
});
```

But, the test passes!  I thought maybe it was something to do with mocha, so I tried running

```
npx tsc test/typings-test.ts
```

But, that worked without error too.

I also tried `require()`ing the compiled js instead of including the ts source & ts-node, but that variation passed as well.

So, what am I missing? Why isn't typescript throwing an error on these mismatched types?

Comment: It's because you are using `require()` function, not `import`, and `require()` is declared in node.js typings to return `any` so `rateLimit` in the test code is effectively untyped.

Comment: That was it, thank you! I also had to pass `--require ts-node/register` to mocha to get past the syntax error, but those two combined got me to the expected failure!

Answer (score 1):

@artem gave me 90% of what I needed to get it working. There were two issues:

1) `ts-node/register` must be required before the test file is parsed, otherwise it's too late to catch the issues. Fix that by adding a `--require ts-node/register` to the mocha command in my package.json:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "eslint . && mocha --require ts-node/register test/*-test.*",
  }
}
```

2) TypeScript only checks types for `import`ed files, so I had to change the require line to:

```
import rateLimit = require("../dist/express-rate-limit");
```